# Get LDAP-Attributes from an dirContext in Java with the "sAMAccountName" instead of "CN"

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm using Java to connect to an Active Directory and now I like to the the `getAttributes` method of an `DirContext` to find all attributes without doing an search.

I found this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JNDI-LDAP/howtoretrieveallattributesofanamedobject.htm and it worked fine - but it needs the CN of the object and at this moment I don't have the CN.

This is my code:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.18.106:389/OU=journaldesigner,DC=dataplan,DC=intern");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "kfriese@dataplan.intern" );
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "fridolin" );
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple" );

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("cn=Klaus Friese");
```

If I replace this line:

```
Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("cn=Klaus Friese");
```

with this

```
Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("sAMAccountName=kfriese");
```

I get an error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'OU=JournalDesigner,DC=dataplan,DC=intern'
```

I searched now for a while but I didn't find anything about that - can I get the attributes with the sAMAccountName? Do I need to do this with the CN?
AD Server is an Microsoft Active Directory.

Thanks 
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Method `getAttributes()` is kind of a specialized search accepting only names for the search filter.  You can't use `sAMAccountName=kfriese` because sAMAccountName is not a name.  So, to read all attributes of an entry you must know its name.